# How to add an image in navigation bar which is partially outside of navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to achieve below behaviour. I tried with below code

```
 let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tab-2"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)
    /*
    navigationController?.navigationBar.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.forEach { $0.clipsToBounds = false }
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1
    
    navigationItem.titleView?.clipsToBounds = false
    navigationController?.view.subviews.forEach { $0.clipsToBounds = false }
    navigationController?.view.clipsToBounds = false
    navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView?.clipsToBounds = false
    navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView?.subviews.forEach { $0.clipsToBounds = false }
     */
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addConstraints([navigationController!.navigationBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
                                                        navigationController!.navigationBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
                                                        navigationController!.navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
                                                        navigationController!.navigationBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)])
```

[image]

I tried different ways which is inside asterisk sign.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: sorry I was about to add code.